# Delete all columns after

Tags: bash, awk, sed

How can I delete everything after nth column in place?

From

```
My name is Chris dfgwer5hy4w5hwret
Bob is his name 41rgadfg agaojpr ge]f8098
A guy called karl gWE GWEG34YHTJ eeg452 yfg
```

To

```
My name is Chris
Bob is his name
A guy called karl
```

Prefer if it also removes any trailing spaces.

I know I can delete a specific column using something like this, but I want to delete everything after the 4th column.

```
sed -i -r 's/\S+//5'
```

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: `cut -d' ' -f1-4`

Comment: It is always recommended to add your efforts which you have put in order to solve your problem in your post too, as we all are here to learn.

Comment: Ye sorry. I know I can delete a column, like this `sed -i -r 's/\S+//5'`. The cut command works, but I dont think you can do that in place? I should have said I would like to do it in place if possible?

Comment: Realised my example was bad. Edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With any awk:

```
$ awk '{sub("([[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]+){"NF-4"}[[:space:]]*$","")}1' file
My name is Chris
Bob is his name
A guy called karl
```

With GNU awk you can do `awk -i inplace 'script' file` to get the same pseudo inplace editing that you get with `sed -i` or `perl -i` and you can manually do externally exactly what they all do internally with any command by just `command 'script' file > tmp && mv tmp file`, e.g.

```
cut -d' ' -f1-4 file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess I dont have the right version of awk because I cant use -i. I will use the tmp solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

Could you please try following(tested in GNU `awk`). For saving results in-place append `> temp_file  && mv temp_file Input_file` to following codes.

```
awk 'NF=4'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** `NF` is `awk`'s out of the box variable which indicates number of fields in current line(by default it considers field separator as space), so I am manually setting its value to 4 here as per OP's question. Now `awk` works on method of pattern/condition and action, so here no action is provided so by default print of current line with edited number of fields will happen.

OR you could use following too as per mention by ghoti sir in comments.

```
awk '{NF=4;$1=$1}1'  Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** Adding a `sed` solution too now. Considering that your actual Input_file is same as shown samples. For saving output to Input_file itself use `sed -i` option for following code.

```
sed 's/\(.* is [^ ]*\)\(.*\)/\1/' Input_file
```

***Solution 3rd:*** In case of your system has `gensub` in `awk` GNU one then following may help you here.

```
awk '{reg="(.* is [^ ]*).*";print gensub(reg, "\\1", 1, $0)}'  Input_file
```

Comment: This works in gawk and mawk, but in the default awk in FreeBSD and macOS, this doesn't change the output. While resetting NF changes NF, it doesn't change $0. Interestingly, `awk '{NF=4;$1=$1}1'` works.

Comment: @ghoti, sure sir thanks for letting know, I have added same in answer too now.

Comment: The effect of decrementing NF is undefined behavior per POSIX so any awk can do whatever it likes when you do that.

Comment: @EdMorton, see I found out your query to GNU `awk` folks mailing list, was writing 3rd solution by using `gensub` of `awk` and was getting warning `warning: gensub: third argument `' treated as 1` saw this URL from you sir :) https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2015-09/msg00015.html   you are great AWK lover, thanks for posting that.

Answer (score 0):

If it's after string and not after nth column, as RavinderSingh13 assumed:

```
cat file.txt | sed 's/^\(My name is [a-z]*\).*/\1/'
```

Comment: You need not to use `cat` with `sed` as `sed is capable of reading files by itself see this once too https://stackoverflow.com/a/53613730/5866580

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer Perl, below would work

```
$ cat chris.txt
My name is Chris dfgwer5hy4w5hwret
Bob is his name 41rgadfg agaojpr ge]f8098
A guy called karl gWE GWEG34YHTJ eeg452 yfg

$ perl -i -lane ' print join " ", @F[0..3] ' chris.txt

$ cat chris.txt
My name is Chris
Bob is his name
A guy called karl

$
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -ri 's/\s+\S+//4g' file
```

Remove the fourth and more group of white space followed by non-white space and return the edited file in place.